# ROR : what is the best way to populate data in select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

***Ruby on Rails*** : what is the best way to populate data in select box

as explained [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'None'})
```

**But best practices says that don't query for data from view**

here `Person.all` will place a query to get all persons

please justify this `Person.all` calling from view

Comment: the examples there dont mean they are the best practice, the answer below works great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you add `@people = Person.all` in your Controller and then `@people.collect { ... }` in your view? This way, you will query in your controller and not in your view.

Answer (score 5):

You are right, don't query data in a view. Better would be to prepare an instance variable in the controller and pass it to the view. But I think this is really debatable here since it's such a minor thing. When you have it in the view like this, you don't have to go back to the controller to find out what the instance variable holds, but if you want to stick to conventions, then you are correct and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't have to go back to the controller to find out what the variable holds"? Technically, Rails binds the instance variables of the controller to the view using [http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Binding.html](Binding), so its really no more or less efficient than a simple method call.

Comment: I screwed up the link apparently. Click this: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Binding.html

Comment: I mean when you are reviewing the code and you are looking at the view... then you don't have to look inside of the controller to find out what the instance variable holds that is used in the view. It's really a matter of convenience I guess and doesn't mean it's good code.

Answer (score 2):

don't fetch all attributes of the object instead use select clause like

```
Person.select('id,name').map{|person| [person.id, person.name]}, and off-course interact
```

with your database like (controller <=> model <=> Database), as per MVC architecture.